# NULL id in SQL statement

Tags: sql, postgresql

```
Select *
from tbl
where id =  '1fa3bcdc9a1cf60f02a2ae774e2cf166'
  or matching_id = 'ea74c270-65fd-46d0-898b-faf1a7bf7e16'
```

My id column below comes back with a NULL for one of my events. They are related using the matching_id key. Is there a way I can write a case statement to populate that id field so its not NULL?

[image]

Comment: *populate that id field* with what?

Comment: You can do this with UPDATE tble where id=null set id="xxx" but this will create duplicate ids. By the sound of the name, ID is expected to be a Primary Key and this implies that it be defined NOT NULL. If you have only one row with the problem then it will work.

Comment: `coalesce(id, '42')`?

Comment: populate the Yellow (NULL field) with its id of '1fa3bcdc9a1cf60f02a2ae774e2cf166'

Comment: Is there a way to write the SQL if I didnt know the id or matching id?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `coalesce()` and in case of `null` id fetch a value (any value?) for the `id` matching the `matching_id` like this:

```
Select 
  coalesce(
    id, 
    (select max(id) from tbl where matching_id = 'ea74c270-65fd-46d0-898b-faf1a7bf7e16')
  ) as id,
  matching_id,
  event_name
from tbl
where 
  id =  '1fa3bcdc9a1cf60f02a2ae774e2cf166'
  or 
  matching_id = 'ea74c270-65fd-46d0-898b-faf1a7bf7e16'
```

Edit.
Try this in case of unknown values:

```
Select 
  coalesce(
    t.id, 
    (select max(id) from tbl where matching_id = t.matching_id)
  ) as id,
  coalesce(
    t.matching_id, 
    (select max(matching_id) from tbl where id = t.id)
  ) as matching_id,
  t.event_name
from tbl t
```

Comment: How could I write the SQL if I didnt know the matching_id or id?

Comment: Post sample data and expected results for this case.

Answer (score 0):

You may be able to utilize the ISNULL() function for this. Maybe something like:

```sql
Select 
    ISNULL(id, matching_id) AS [myid],
    matching_id,
    event_name
from tbl
where id =  '1fa3bcdc9a1cf60f02a2ae774e2cf166'
  or matching_id = 'ea74c270-65fd-46d0-898b-faf1a7bf7e16'
```

Comment: `[id]` is an invalid identifier in SQL.

Comment: `[myid]` is also invalid - the square brackets are invalid characters in an identifier in SQL unless you use double quotes, e.g. `"[myid]"`

Answer (score 0):

Ended up writing something like this..

[snapshot [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eI5Ex.png)

```
with find_event AS (
  Select tbl1. id, tbl1.matching_id
  from tbl1 
  where tbl1.id IS NOT NULL
  )

Select
  CASE WHEN find_event. id IS NOT NULL
    THEN find_event. id
  WHEN find_event.id IS NULL
    THEN tbl2. id
  ELSE tbl2. id
END as final_id,

  tbl2.matching_id,
  tbl2. id,
  tbl2.event_name,
  find _event. id as find_canonical_id
from tbl2 
left JOIN find_event on find_event.matching_id = tbl2.matching_id
where    
    tbl2.transaction_canonical_id =  '1fa3bcdc9a1cf60f02a2ae774e2cf166'
  or
  tbl2.matching_id = 'ea74c270-65fd-46d0-898b-faf1a7bf7e16'
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to replace the column values with the values from your parameters, you could use something like this:

```
with ids (id, mid) as (
  values 
    ('1fa3bcdc9a1cf60f02a2ae774e2cf166', 'ea74c270-65fd-46d0-898b-faf1a7bf7e16')
)
Select coalesce(tbl.id, ids.id), 
       tbl.matching_id, 
       tbl.event_name
from tbl
  join ids on ids.id = tbl.id or ids.mid = tbl.matching_id;
```